# Do i still have to insert id values after using this script?

Tags: oracle11g

I have a script below - I dont know if it will produce the same effect as auto increment. When i begin inserting rows into my database, i dont want to insert the id. I want the database to generate and insert them automatically when i insert non-id rows.

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable
(id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR2(30));

CREATE SEQUENCE myschema.test1_sequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

create or replace trigger myschema.auto_increment
before insert on myschema.mytable
for each row
begin
select test1_sequence.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work, except that you don't have to use

```
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
```

because `PRIMARY KEY` already contains the `NOT NULL` constraint, so

```
id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
```

is enough.